# NodeJS append base64 to file

Tags: node.js, base64

i try to implement a chunk file upload in my React application. 
I'm using blob.slice and Filreader to get base64 and send it as POST to my server.

```
const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5;
const blob = new Blob([file]);
const currentChunk = blob.slice(0, chunkSize);

const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(currentChunk);
reader.onload = (e) => { 
    const base64Data = reader.result.replace('data:;base64,', '');
    axios.post('url', {
        data: base64Data
    }).then((response) => {
        // .. Get next chunk and so on
    })
}
```

On my nodejs server side (with express) i try to append every base64 chunk to a file to restore the whole file:

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync(testFile, req.body.data, {encoding: 'base64'});
```

If i upload now a file for example with 500mb, the restored file on the server is always 5.2MB

Comment: can you try `fs.appendFileSync(testFile, req.body.data, {encoding: 'base64'});`?

Comment: it should work. according to docs, it should create file if it does not exist https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options

Comment: let me know how you go :)

Comment: @Theo it works, thanks so much.

Comment: ok i'll post it as answer @Pukka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options), this should do the job

```
fs.appendFileSync(testFile, req.body.data, {encoding: 'base64'});
```